# C# how to pass query string parameters in a post call

Tags: c#, rest, http-post, query-string

I have to call an external rest service from wpf application. I do not have any control on the service. When I make a request to the service using a rest client (e.g. Postman) it works fine i.e. success is returned. A post call is done to this URL:

http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/rest/login?username=usr&password=pwd

You can see that I have to pass username and password in querystring.

But when I do the same from my application the service returns failed. Here is my code:

```
string EndPoint = "http://mydomain.com:38080/workshop/";
string parameters = "username=usr&password=pwd";

CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(EndPoint);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("rest/login", new StringContent(parameters)).Result;

Task task = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var stream = t.Result;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
});

task.Wait();
```

It seems that the service is expecting parameters in querystring whereas my code is passing them in request header. So how do I pass the parameters in querystring in a post call?

Comment: `PostAsync` will send a `POST`.  You want a `GET` - sending the parameters in the URL.  It may be worth reading up on the two

Comment: Yes i know postasync will send a post call. It is service's requirement to send a post call.

Comment: if you copy the url generated by postman into your browser and send it, does it return what you expect?

Comment: nope, it shows HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: Radical.  I'd grab a great tool called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and see what is actually getting sent by your code vs. postman's

Comment: try changing your client.postasync to a concatenated URL -> `Client.PostAsync("rest/login?username=usr&password=pwd", new StringContent(""))`

Comment: it works fine in PostMan if i set parameters in URL params but not if i set them in Headers.

Comment: thanks man! it worked. but now there is another issue that in PostMan I can see a cookie is returned but my application does not receive it. Fiddler also shows that no cookie was sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57444/discussion-between-haris-and-jonesy).